# Tangent line approximation

Tags: calculus, tangent-line

I am doing the calculus course on edX and I stumbled across this explanation for a problem (I am not asking for the answer, just elaboration on a specific part).

$$x = 100$$

$$g(x) = \sqrt{x} = 10$$

But how is it that $g'(x) = 0.05$?

I thought that the formula was $g'(x) = 1/2* x^{-1/2}$: But when I plugged $x = 100$, I didn't get $0.05$ as the result.

Comment: $\frac1{2\sqrt{100}}=.05$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a tutorial/reference for formatting mathematical statements on this site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get $0.05$ as the result of $g'(100)$:

$$\dfrac12(100^{-1/2})=\dfrac12\times\dfrac1{100^{1/2}}=\dfrac12\times\dfrac1{10}=0.05$$

Comment: Ah I see! Yeah this is so much clearer now, I guess I get confused with the power notation and all. Thanks a lot!